# include a php file in another without it running(can't use functions)

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to make a search bar for my website kinda like google's, where it automatically updates the results
I am using php and AJAX to do it, here is the AJAX piece, just so i can explain further
`edited below`
so hopefully, you all know AJAX, i called the `search()` function in an event attribute in the html form onkeyup
it is running the AJAX correctly, i tested it with a little `alert('hello!');`
now my problem is that i get an undefined index error in the following code :

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
require '../search.php';
$term = $_POST['searchword'];
$type = $_POST['searchtype'];
echo $term . $type;
  $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$term);
  $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$term%' AND `type` = '$type'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $name = $row['username'];
    $ntype = $row['type'];
    $id = $row['user_id'];
    echo "<a href = \"user.php?id=$id\"><div class=\"col-lg-12 result\">$name</br>$ntype</div></a>";
  }if($rowcnt = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo"<div class=\"col-lg-12 result center\">No results found</div>";
  }

 ?>
```

the undefined index error is for `$term` and `$type`, which is `$_POST['searchword'];` and `$_POST['searchtype'];`
i went through the code and i realized that the search.php page isnt included...  so "searchword" and "searchtype" are not defined, so i tried including it, now everytime i hit a button in the search bar i get a second search form, because the code is running search.php onkeyup also, so i was wondering if there are any ways to avoid this from happening
and btw i still get the undefined index error, even with it being included
Those are all the files i am using :
search.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'res/connection.php';
include 'res/loggedinmenu.php';
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])){
  echo"<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.href = 'index.php';},2000);
  </script>";
  echo "
  <div class=\"alert alert-info\">
    <strong>You are not logged in!</strong> in 2 seconds you will be redirected to the login page
  </div>
  ";
}
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title> search for other developers or owners</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/profile.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <style>
   body{
     background-color:#dcdcdc;
   }
   .all{
       margin-top:110px;
   }
   .search{
     border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
     background-color:#e4e4e4;
     display:inline;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #ccc;
     margin-bottom:35px;
   }
   .header{
     width:100%;
     background-color:#3928f2;
     color:white;
     text-align:center;
     padding-top:15px;
     padding-bottom:15px;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-size:20px;
   }
   .form{
     padding-top:20px;
     border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
   }
   .result{
     font-size:20px;
     margin-top:15px;
     padding-bottom:5px;
     border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
     text-decoration:none;
   }
   .result :hover{
     text-decoration:none;
   }
   .center{
     text-align:center;
   }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <?php menu(); ?>
   <div class="container all">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2">
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-8 search">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12 header">search for a developer or an owner</div>
         <div class="col-lg-12 form">
         <form action="" method="post" style="text-align:center;">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
           <label for="term">Search term :</label>
           <input type="text" onkeyup="search()" class="form-control" name="searchword" id="searchbar" value = "<?php if (isset($_GET['term'])){ echo $_GET['term']; }?>"/>
         </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6">
           <label for="type">looking for a :</label>
           <select name="searchtype" class="form-control" id="stype">
             <option>owner</option>
             <option>developer</option>
           </select></br>
       </div>
     </div>
         </div>
         </form>
       <hr>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
          <div  id="results" class="col-lg-12">
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET['term']) && isset($_GET['type'])){
            $term = $_GET['term'];
            $type = $_GET['type'];
          }else{
            $term = $_POST['searchword'];
            $type = $_POST['searchtype'];
          }
            if($term == ""){
              echo '<div class="col-lg-12 result center">Type in the box above to start searching</div>';
            }else{
              $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$term);
              $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type);
              $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$term%' OR `username` LIKE '%$term' AND `type` = '$type'";
              $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $name = $row['username'];
                $ntype = $row['type'];
                $id = $row['user_id'];
                echo "<a href = \"user.php?id=$id\"><div class=\"col-lg-12 result\">$name</br>$ntype</div></a>";
              }if($rowcnt = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
                echo"<div class=\"col-lg-12 result center\">No results found</div>";
              }
            }
             ?>
          </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2">
         <!--leave empty -->
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
 <script>
 function search(){
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "res/searchsyntax.php";
   var trm = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
   var tpe = document.getElementById('stype').value;
   var params = "term=" + term + "&type=" + tpe;
   http.open("POST", url, true);

   //Send the proper header information along with the request
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
   http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

   http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }
   }
   http.send(params);
 }
 </script>
```

res/searchsyntax.php :

```
    <?php
require 'connection.php';
$term = $_GET['term'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
if($term == ""){
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12 result center">Type in the box above to start searching</div>';
}else{
  $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$term);
  $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$term%' AND `type` = '$type'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $name = $row['username'];
    $ntype = $row['type'];
    $id = $row['user_id'];
    echo "<a href = \"user.php?id=$id\"><div class=\"col-lg-12 result\">$name</br>$ntype</div></a>";
  }if($rowcnt = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo"<div class=\"col-lg-12 result center\">No results found</div>";
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: two downvotes ? atleast comment saying why would you downvote

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are not sending the post parameters i.e.  "searchword" and "searchtype" through AJAX to the PHP code.

[This code](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) demonstrates on how to do this.

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try it, and this is my first AJAX piece of code i ever written, i did not know about this, btw do i need to set the request header for what i am doing also ?

Comment: and how can set in the params : term=$_POST['searchword']&type=$_POST['searchtype'] ? should i do this ? var params = "term=<? $_POST['searchword']?>&type=<?php $_POST['searchtype']?>" and thanks in advance @Harshit

Comment: Yes, at least you should set `http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`. Through javascript, get the values of `searchword` & send it through AJAX. You haven't shown your HTML code!!

Comment: i have edited the question, the new code is the one where i did what you told me to do, it still didnt work

Comment: where is `$term = $_POST['searchword'];` in the new code of `res/searchsyntax.php` ?

Comment: i just edited the code in the question to what i exactly have in my editor, you can check it out

Comment: We are sending the values through POST method. Why using `$_GET['term'];` ?

Comment: i have edited it to $_POST but still same result, so i tested with an alert message, i put it in here, http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = http.responseText;
      alert('hi');
    }
   } but i dont get the hi alert

Comment: Change `var trm = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;`, `term` instead of `trm`.

Comment: Yeah, you could use JQuery!! Better & Simple

Comment: JavaScript errors are difficult to trace since they don't show any error. To trace the error, go step by step. Write first line with an alert statement & check if alert popup is displaying, if yes, then write second line & check again.

Comment: hey if i make the onkeyup function, which is search() like this : function search() { document.write(' php code goes here ')} will it work ?

Comment: i know jquery but ive been thinking of a way to do this through jquery and i havent found one yet, im not good with implementing php inside js, howndonu recommend i do it